# Like Button doen`t count the like + js error

Tags: debugging, plugins, button, count, facebook-like

I include the like button in my website. When I click the like button it shows one like and the item is correctly posted on facebook, but when I reload my website the one like count is missing—it shows zero already.  There is only a javascript error in the firebug:

> uncaught exception: Error: http://www.facebook.com wurde die
>   Erlaubnis für das Lesen der Eigenschaft Proxy.InstallTrigger
>   verweigert. (uncaught exception: Error: http://www.facebook.com
>   permission was refused for reading the property Proxy.InstallTrigger.)

here is my code:

```
     <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.mywebsite.com/test_v2/joinnowpage/2_281&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=302&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:302px; height:25px;"></iframe>
```

I try it with another website and it works perfectly:

```
     <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.a1-dresden.de/contest_detail/1732_Back+to+Future&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=302&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:302px; height:25px;"></iframe>
```

I used the facebook Object Debugger, but there is no error.

So where is the different? What did i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not a solution to your problem, but have a look at Bugzilla@Mozilla, there is a bug report to your problem:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=Proxy.InstallTrigger
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701029

Perhaps posting your experiences in Bugzilla@Mozilla or voting up the bug report could help speed up the creation of a bugfix.

Comment: this question is a possible duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058726/facebook-like-plugin-wizard-the-like-button-unclick-itself